# How to avoid superfluous variables in do notation?

Tags: haskell, do-notation

Say in a Haskell do-notation block, I wish to have a variable `is_root` indicating if I am root:

```
import System.Posix.User
main = do
    uid <- getRealUserID
    is_root <- return $ uid == 0
```

That annoying `uid` variable is only used in that one place. I wish instead I could write this:

```
main = do
    is_root <- getRealUserID == 0
```

But of course that won't compile.

How can I get rid of superfluous variables like `uid`? Here's the best I've come up with:

```
import System.Posix.User
main = do
    is_root <- getRealUserID >>= return . ((==) 0)
```

Blech! Is there a nicer way?

Comment: This doesn't get rid of the extra variable, but you should also be using `let is_root = uid == 0` instead of `is_root <- return $ uid == 0`.  It's not a monadic computation, so there's no need to wrap it in `return` and use bind.

Comment: I don't see anything ugly in your attempt, just in the right operand of bind it may be shorten to `return . (== 0)`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One way is

```
fmap (== 0) getRealUserID
```

Comment: Note that `m >>= return . f` (as in the code in the question) is required to be equal to `fmap f m` by the `Monad` laws: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Monad.html#t:Monad

Comment: You can also use the Applicative instance, something like:  `is_root <- (==0) <$> getRealUserID`, which I think reads a little better.

Comment: @PeterHall `(<$>)` is still a synonym for `fmap` from the `Functor` instance, it's just frequently used together with applicative notation (and re-exported from `Control.Applicative` for that purpose).

Comment: (<$>) is also in Data.Functor

Comment: As the computation runs in `IO` context for which (with proper imports) `Functor`, `Applicative` and of course `Monad` instances do exist, you may apply whatever mapping function as you please.

Answer (score 6):

(I assume your goal is to limit the scope of `uid`, not to just be pointfree for its own sake)

In a simple case like this, [@pdw's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25314870/570682) is probably the way to go.  The operators `<$>` and `<*>` from `Control.Applicative` are particularly helpful here.

```
foo = do
  are_same <- (==) <$> doThis <*> doThat
```

In slightly more complicated situations, you could use a nested-`do`:

```
complicatedEq :: This -> That -> IO Bool

main = do
  are_same <- do
    this <- doThis
    that <- doThatBasedOn this
    complicatedEq this that
  ... rest ...
```

Anything significantly long probably deserves to be its own function.